# How to remove weird blank border around my photo?

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the silly question, im still new to coding

Im trying to make a photo fill my whole screen (its not my background image, im using another GIF as the background) but there's a blank border surrouding the image that I cant figure out how to remove. Here's my html and a simple CSS that I tried to use to fix it, and a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDJdn.png) of the problem.

```
    <div id=mainpic>
        <img src="https://felizcumpleanos.neocities.org/jardines/fondo%20jardin%20main.GIF">
    </div>

    <style>
      #mainpic, img{
        margin:0; 
        padding:0;
      }
    </style>
```

Comment: The border is most probably due to settings on the parent element or body element respectively. Try to add `body {margin: 0; padding; 0}` rule

Comment: That's not a border. It is the overflow of the image on the x axis